# Drupal 6 Using SWF Tools to display an .swf files

Tags: drupal, video, flash

I'm trying to display an .swf file (with an accompanying .flv file) using SWF Tools, which I understand is possible.

So far, I have:

1. Created the field "video".
2. Enabled the SWF Tools module (version 6.25).

At this point, I'm really stuck.  I created a block in Views, but it only displays an anchor link to the .swf file.  I've read "Installing SWF Tools" (http://drupal.org/node/303203) but don't really understand it.

I'm hoping for some simple directions so I can get this finished and move on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the swf tools filter for your input format.